# Microsoft Word: Change Font of Characters Missing In Default Font

Tags: vba, fonts, ms-word, replace, special-characters

I am trying to use VBA in Microsoft Word to automatize highly repetative operations on large documents.

The situation is this: I have a technical text containing a lot of special characters, e.g. ❨  (U+2768) and ❩ (U+2769). The text is chiefly typeset in Cambria, but some of the special characters are not found in this font. However, I do know for a fact, that all characters used in the document are present in DejaVu Sans Mono. Hence, I would like all characters to be in Cambria except for those that cannot be displayed in this font -- those characters I want displayed in DejaVu Sans Mono.

In Microsoft Word 2007, I could easily achieve this by Ctrl+A, set font to DejaVu Sans Mono, set font to Cambria. The second change of font would only change the font of those characters that can be displayed in Cambria.

However, in Microsoft Word 2010, this apparently does not work. Every single character gets the font Cambria, and instead of displaying the characters not found in Cambria, the boxed question mark symbol is displayed.

To overcome this, I have turned to VBA. It is very easy to change the font of a given character, e.g.

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Text = ChrW(10088)
Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = ChrW(10088)
Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Name = "DejaVu Sans Mono"
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

However, it is not exceedingly fun to write the above code for each and every character in (C(DejaVu) ∖ C(Cambria)) ∩ C(Doc) where C(DejaVu), C(Cambria), and C(Doc) is the set of all characters in DejaVu Sans Mono, Cambria, and my document, respectively.

Is there any (reasonably simple) way to accomplish this automatically? Surely Microsoft Word knows which characters are found in Cambria and which are not. I want all instances of those characters that are not found in Cambria, to be given the font DejaVu Sans Mono.

Comment: Surely it would be easier code to put all special characters in the second font (DejaVu)? Is the any reason why you do not wish to do this?

Comment: @Remou: In general, Cambria and DejaVu Sans Mono do not look very well together. But characters like U+2768 are so special that this is not important. Also, most "special characters" are actually available in Cambria. Furthermore, how do you define a special character? Are Greek letters special characters?

Comment: Word does not know the which characters are present in which font. That is left to the end user to use the font face that has the glyphs needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer will help you achieve your goal: [Script for changing fonts in a Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339972/script-for-changing-fonts-in-a-word-document/3127795#3127795)

Comment: How is that going to help with the OP's problem? The linked answer just provides a means to replace one font with another, doesn't it?

Comment: I guess because my answer was referenced, I'll say that it will would only help if the character is identified in the loop and then replaced. The recursion is definetely faster than `Selection.Find`, which uses a RegEx engine of sorts, which puts the character detection through at least one extra pass. But the above code could also be modified to use an array and something as simple as a `Select Case   Case Array(ChrW(10088), ChrW(10087)) Case Else 'Do nothing   End Select` and it would get the job done.

Comment: I was just trying to help. Sorry for all the trouble I caused :|