# How to change font in word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm wondering how can I change the font (+ color and some font style) for the whole word document (excluding the page headers, if it's possible) by using C# ?

If You know any libraries (also commercial) feel free to let me know.

(After changing the font, I'll convert that word document to PDF using ABCPdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the library you would loop through the content (Pages/Paragraphs etc.) and change whatever font attribute you want...

Since you don't say which type of application you build - in case it is a pure desktop application and Word is guranteed to be installed locally you can use [Office Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.aspx). [BEWARE that Office Interop is NOT supported by MS in server-scenarios (like IIS, ASP.NET. Windows Service, WCF etc.)](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2).

IF Word is not guaranteed to be installed and/or your application is not a desktop application and your Word documents are always DOCX files you could use [OpenXML SDK V 2 from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx) (free).

Otherwise I can recommend [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) (commercial) - works with old DOC and current DOCX and is usable in any type of application (desktop, ASP.NET, Windows Service etc.).

Comment: Well, it'll be the APN.NET MVC 3 app and also it will be processing both .doc and .docx files. I'll look around the Aspose.Words library. Thanks for the info about the Office Interop in web scenarios, it probably saves me a lot of time

Comment: @Tony you are welcome :-) please don't forget to mark as accepted answers that are of help, this helps other looking for an answer (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Hmm, after a quick glance of the article about the Office Interop in the server scenario I'm wondering - because I only wannt to play with the fonts in the doc/docx file - if it also won't be working properly in that case. It seems not to be a very complex operation that could relates to points included in the 'Problems using server-side Automation of Office'. Do You have any experience with Office Interop on the server scenario ?

Comment: @Tony the link points out several aspects - legal (licensing!), security, multi-threading and several other things... in my experience Office Interop ion the server shows rather strange results from not working (tends to happen in newer windows version) to requiring risky security setting... sometimes just open and save leads to problems with complex files etc. - it cost me lots of headaches... even for the smallest operation NEVER use server-side Office Interop.

Comment: now I see that I must keep looking for the solution. The Aspose.Word's library seems to be fine for that scenario, but I see that the PDF manipulation is their separate product, which would raise the overall licensing costs. I still can't find an answer, if my found library - ABCPdf can manipulate the font in the office file (as far as I know it offers the conversion Office -> PDF). Or maybe You know a library to manipulate office files and canvert them to PDF ?

Comment: @Tony not really... Aspose.Words can generate PDF files (works fine)... if you really need to manipulate the old DOC fiel format there are not many components out there (searched very long time without much success for a project I am working on)...

Comment: right now I'm able to change a font in the DOX file (using OpenXML) but I can't find anything for the DOC format. You've mentioned that You have been searching for a solution for the DOC format, have You found anything ? I suppose taht You had to manipulate the DOC file

Comment: @Tony the only things I found were Aspose.Words and something called gembox... I can recommend Aspose.Words, didn't try gembox...

Comment: Ok, so I'll check it, I'm tired of searching anything for the doc format. Thank You for Your time and help, Yahia

Answer (score 1):

Handling Office documents in .NET is a quite straight forward task. Have a look at [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.aspx), it is pretty well documented. Here is another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339972/script-for-changing-fonts-in-a-word-document) on to how you can change a word document font style using .NET (the example is in VB but is easily convertible to C#)

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading on [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

(You can google some user-friendly examples, there are tons)

Later on,  read about [Text Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b7k14a4.aspx)

Easy, isn't it?